# Privacy laws and the Azure platform

Tags: azure, privacy

While privacy laws are normally outside the domain of us developers, I do think it's an important topic to keep here at SO because we developers should take the responsibility to warn our employers if they want something that would break some laws... In this case, privacy-laws... Normally, we developers don't have to think much about legal stuff, but this seems to become a much bigger issue these days. It's too easy for employers to forget about these things but the consequences of these laws could be very harmful for future developments...

---

Many countries dictate limitations on how companies are allowed to store privacy-sensitive data in databases. For example, social security numbers, bank account numbers, criminal pasts, former employees, birthdate, relatives, sexual orientation and whatever more. Such data is limited to certain restrictions that could differ from country to country...
The Azure platform makes it even more complex since Azure is owned by an US company (Microsoft) and the US law dictates that Microsoft needs to hand over data if the Feds need it for some research. ([This article](http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2011/06/microsoft-says-it-will-give-yo.php) highlights it.) Thus, this could put Azure in conflict with specific laws in certain areas of this world.

**What I need to know is which countries would have such a restriction that I cannot offer customers in those areas an Azure-based solution that would process privacy-sensitive data?** (Thus, those countries would need a non-azure, localized solution!)
This is important because I need to display a disclaimer warning those users, making it clear that they might be in violation. Users will tell from which country they are so basically the disclaimer is just limited to those users. (Each user will be maintaining data for possible hundreds of their customers each, so it's a lot of sensitive data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many different sets of laws for you to be able to give or even keep up to date that kind of information on your web site.

What you could do is make them aware of the problem and say that users must take in to consideration laws in their country before signing up.